# Formatting data for display in SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, vba

In what cases is it appropriate to do presentation formatting of values within a SQL query or view such that the values are ready to be displayed directly to the user in the application?

Background:
In the process of converting some queries written in a legacy Microsoft Access database, I have come across a significant amount of 'display formatting', that is, embedded VBA/SQL that exists only to prepare the result to be directly displayed on a form or report. From a pure programming perspective this seems very wrong to me, but I am not familiar enough with SQL to know if this is acceptable.

Here's an example from the query I have open on my screen now...

```
Left(Salespersons.Salesperson,1) & ". " & imTextAfterSpace(Salespersons.Salesperson)
```

This is taking a full name and converting it like so: 'Joe Smith' ==> 'J. Smith'

In a C# application for example, it would be poor practice to write code like this:

```
var theTime = DateTime.Now.ToString()
```

... later

```
someLabel.Text = theTime;
```

Because the richness/semantics of the original object type (`DateTime` in that case) is lost as soon as you turn it into a string.

Comment: There isn't a very objective and complete answer to this question.

Comment: Umm, that looks like VBA, and not SQL.  And that would make this a very different question.

Comment: It's tagged with both because in MS Access, people write VBA in the middle of SQL queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct when you say it's a bad idea - it just makes the SQL code base very difficult to maintain and easily bug prone.

In an ideal world, any formatting would happen in a middle or ui layer of the application.

When is it appropriate? This is by no means an absolute list, but the few cases i can quickly think of are:

- -When you have no control of the UI layer.
- -When you have to integrate with a legacy application

Comment: Thanks. I think in this case, both of your situations apply, unfortunately.